# ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES error in Django project

Tags: python, django

I made simple reservation website in django. And It works just fine in dedicated server but it returns this error when i try to migrate it in local machine.
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`
I haven'touched anything in DATABASES. So it looks like this

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

Is there any possible solution for this problem?

I've tried some solutions that i found online such as adding
`from .database import *` 
But it didn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

The name of database is wrong. Please follow steps to solve the issue

Import the os

```
import os
```

then mention the name like this

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```